# Simple and intuitive tool for generating simple diagrams

Tags: graphics, arrows, graphs

I am looking for a simle and intuitive tool for generating simple diagrams to be included in `tex` document. The graph I want to convert into `tex` is given below:

[image]

Ideally, I would like to end up with `tex` code, but unfortunately I am at time shortage and need a tool with really **low entry threshold**. Thus, I would be satisfied with any other graphical tool which may help to generate something like this (favourably, with *level adjusting assistant* or something like this (`Paint` will not do the trick ;) )).

Comment: For mz, the implest is `pstricks` , and more specifically the `pst-node` module and its `\psmatrix` environment, as it has a latex-like syntax, and is comparatively well documented.

Comment: For that simple matrix-like diagram I'd simply use `xypic` and its `xymatrix` command...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution in asymptote using recursion.  Just change the first five lines of the code to modify the output.  Make sure the number of initial values is a power of 2 or it will probably throw an error.

```
unitsize(1inch);
real xspacing = 0.5;
real yspacing = 0.5;
pair[] values = { (1,1), (7,9), (2,8), (8,6) };
string[] labels = { "$y_i$", "$d_2$", "$c_2$", "$d_1$", "$c_1$", "$d_0$", "$c_0$"};
// -------------------------------
real xstart = 0.0;
void drawTree(pair[] values, string[] labels, int level = 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i)
    {
        pair loc1 = (xstart + 2 * i * xspacing, -yspacing * level);
        pair loc2 = (xstart + (2 * i + 1) * xspacing, loc1.y);
        if (level == 0)
        {
            label(string(values[i].x), loc1);
            label(string(values[i].y), loc2);
        }
        pair loc3 = (loc1 + loc2) / 2.0 - (0, yspacing);
        label(string(values[i].y - values[i].x), loc3);
        pair loc4 = loc3 - (0, yspacing);
        label(string(values[i].y + values[i].x), loc4);
        draw(subpath(loc1--loc3, 0.15, 0.85), 0.3+dashed, Arrow);
        draw(subpath(loc2--loc3, 0.15, 0.85), 0.3+dashed, Arrow);
        draw(subpath(loc1--loc4, 0.07, 0.93), 0.3+black, Arrow);
        draw(subpath(loc2--loc4, 0.07, 0.93), 0.3+black, Arrow);
    }
    if (level == 0)
    {
        real x = 2 * values.length * xspacing;
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i)
        {
            label(labels[i], (x, -i * yspacing));
        }
    }
    if (values.length < 2) { return; }
    pair[] newvalues;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2)
    {
        newvalues.push((values[i].x + values[i].y, values[i+1].x + values[i+1].y));
    }
    xstart += xspacing / 2.0;
    xspacing *= 2.0;
    drawTree(newvalues, labels, level + 2);
}
drawTree(values, labels);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @James! In fact, I like your solution the most. I like the `recursion` code concept and the fact you have caught the "mathematical idea" behind the tree.

Comment: I have just realised that I am not perfectly sure how to use the piece of code you have supplied. I believe it is `tex` code (I was not aware I can perform `loops` and `Arrays` there) but I am not sure if I should include it between `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` clauses and if any additional packages should be supplied.

Comment: You need to compile it with Asymptote - the executable is called `asy` and (by default) it produces a PDF that you can include in your TeX source with `\includegraphics`

Comment: Thank you! I work under Ubuntu and I quickly compiled it in `Texmaker`. The only think to change in default `Texmaker` environment was a build way which I set as "Asymptote" (see [pic](http://i.imgur.com/LDgW8ou.png)). The "View PDF" was unavailable, but the PDF was created as a result of compilation (in the `asy` file firectory).

Answer (score 6):

My first choice would be `pgfplots` and `tikz`. 
It lets you draw right in Latex.

You can try something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{>=stealth} % arrowheads 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (12,4)node[above]{24} -- (8,0)node[below]{42};
\draw [->] (4,4)node[above]{18} -- (8,0);
\node at (17,0)[right]{$ c_0 $};
\draw [->,dashed] (12,4) -- (8,2);
\draw [->,dashed] (4,4) -- (8,2);
\node at (17,2) [right]{$ d_0 $};
\node at(17,4) [right]{$ c_1 $};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I just started on the image you postet.
The result will look like this:

[image: result]
Hope this gets you on track.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Perhaps editing your answer to include a graphic of the result would improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: Hi @Ben! Thank you for your answer (+1). I wish I coould mark everyone's correct answer as **answer** and assign points to them. I really appreciate your inpact.

Answer (score 6):

I also suggest Tikz, but more specifically the Tikz trees. Probably you could automatise this but I can't think of a way so the solution is manual. I was going to provide a small sample for you to complete, but I had already finished it on my own, so here it is.

Basically the level distance is `2cm` but the middle child is shifted down of `1cm` so it's midway and the nodes on the side have a level distance of `1cm` so they align properly.

The empty arrow tip is done thanks to the `arrows.meta` library. You can see more tips in the chapter *"16.5 Reference: Arrow Tips"*, page 203, of the [Tikz Manual (v 3.0.0)](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\tikzset{
    kit/.style={dashed,<-,>={Kite[open]}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    level distance=2cm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=8mm},
    rightn/.style={level distance=1cm},
    <-,>={Latex},
    no edge/.style={
           edge from parent/.style={draw=none}}]

\node (root) {42} [grow=up]
    child{node (24) {24}
        child{node (14r) {14}
            child{node (6b) {6}}
            child[no edge]{node[yshift=-1cm] (2m) {-2}}
            child{node (8r) {8}}
        }
        child[no edge]{node[yshift=-1cm] (4) {4}}
        child{node (10) {10}
            child{node (8l) {8}}
            child[no edge]{node[yshift=-1cm] (6c) {6}}
            child{node (21) {2}}
        }}
    child[no edge]{node[yshift=-1cm] (6) {6}}
    child{node (18) {18}
        child{node (16) {16}
            child{node (9) {9}}
            child[no edge]{node[yshift=-1cm] (2b) {2}}
            child{node (7) {7}}
        }
        child[no edge]{node[yshift=-1cm] (14l) {14}}
        child{node (2) {2}
            child{node (1r) {1}}
            child[no edge]{node[yshift=-1cm] (0) {0}}
            child{node (1l) {1}}
        }
};

\node[right=6cm of root,level distance=1cm] {$c_0$} [grow=up]
    child[no edge,rightn]{node {$d_0$}
    child[no edge,rightn]{node {$c_1$}
    child[no edge,rightn]{node {$d_1$}
    child[no edge,rightn]{node {$c_2$}
    child[no edge,rightn]{node {$d_2$}
    child[no edge,rightn]{node {$y_i$}}
}}}}};

\draw[kit] (6) edge (18) edge (24);
\draw[kit] (14l) edge (16) edge (2);    
\draw[kit] (4) edge (14r) edge (10);
\draw (0) edge (1r) edge (1l);
\draw (2b) edge (7) edge (9);
\draw (6c) edge (21) edge (8l);
\draw (2m) edge (8r) edge (6b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Alenanno for your inpact, especially for mentioning the `Tikz trees`!

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Ben's `tikzpicture` module, and turning it into a macro

```
\blivet[supress top #]{top-left #}{top-right #}{width}
```

has allowed me a start on it.  More automation remains to be done.  The height of the blivets are defined with `\def\blivetheight{3}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}\setstackgap{S}{-5pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{>=stealth} % arrowheads 
\def\blivetheight{3}
\newcommand\blivet[4][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \def\topleft{#2}\def\topright{#3}%
  \else
    \def\topleft{}\def\topright{}%
  \fi
\makebox[#4cm]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (#4,\blivetheight)node[above]{\topright} -- 
  (#4/2,0)node[below]{\the\numexpr#2+#3\relax};
\draw [->] (0,\blivetheight)node[above]{\topleft} -- (#4/2,0);
\draw [->,dashed] (#4,\blivetheight) -- (#4/2,\blivetheight/2)%
  node[below]{\the\numexpr#3-#2\relax};
\draw [->,dashed] (0,\blivetheight) -- (#4/2,\blivetheight/2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\newcommand\gap[1]{\unskip\hspace{#1cm}\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\Shortstack{
  \blivet{1}{1}{1.5}\gap{1.5}\blivet{7}{9}{1.5}\gap{1.5}
  \blivet{2}{8}{1.5}\gap{1.5}\blivet{8}{6}{1.5}\\
  \blivet[x]{2}{16}{3}\gap{3}\blivet[x]{10}{14}{3}\\
  \blivet[x]{18}{24}{6}
}\qquad
{\setstackgap{S}{1.5cm}\setstackEOL{ }\raisebox{4pt}{%
  \ensurestackMath{\Shortstack{y_i d_2 c_2 d_1 c_1 d_0 c_0}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Steven! Thank you for your answer and for developing Ben's `tikzpicture` idea!